# Keras Generator Output vs Direct File Read Produced Drastically Different Model Results

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, generator

In TensorFlow Keras, I have created a generator to feed a model .fit() function in order to supply the contents of a file. I don't get any errors but the model generated is nonsensical if it is fed from the generator while the model is correct when fed the file more directly.

The model is fed a file containing input rows as follows:

```
0.1,0.2,0.0,0.4,0.0
...
```

and another file containing output rows as follows:

```
0.5,0.4,0.7,0.2,0.6
...
```

in order to create a multi-input to multi-output mapping function.

Any suggestions on how the generator is incorrectly creating the required data?

The code is the following and the use of the generator or direct file read is controlled by the 'is_multifile' variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# mlp for multi-output regression
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# get the dataset
def get_dataset_from_file():
        X = pd.read_csv("/home/learning/training/Output_00.csv")
        Y = pd.read_csv("/home/learning/training/Input_00.csv")
        return ( X.values,Y.values )

# get the dataset in pieces
def get_dataset_from_files( epoch_count, batch_size ):
        for e in range(0,epoch_count):
                print( "Epoch: "+str(e)+"/"+str(epoch_count) )
                for id in range(0,1):
                        if (id<10):
                                id_text = "0"+str(id)
                        else:
                                id_text = str(id)
                        X = pd.read_csv("/home/learning/training/Output_"+id_text+".csv")
                        Y = pd.read_csv("/home/learning/training/Output_"+id_text+".csv")
                        X_values = X.to_numpy()
                        Y_values = Y.to_numpy()
                        length = math.ceil(len(X_values)/batch_size)
                        X_split = np.array_split( X_values, length )
                        Y_split = np.array_split( Y_values, length )
                        for i in range(0,length):
                                yield( X_split[ i ], Y_split[ i ] )

# get the model
def get_model( node_count, layer_count, input_count, output_count, optimizer ):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        for i in range(0,layer_count):
                model.add( layers.Dense( int(node_count/layer_count), input_dim=input_count, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu' ) )
        model.add(layers.Dense( output_count ))
        model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer)
        return model

# Configuration
is_multifile=False
batch_size=32
epoch_count=1
optimizer='adam'
node_count=80
layer_count=2
steps_per_epoch=54988

X,Y = get_dataset_from_file()
input_count,output_count = X.shape[1],Y.shape[1]
model = get_model( node_count, layer_count, input_count, output_count, optimizer )

if (is_multifile):
        loss_history = model.fit( get_dataset_from_files( epoch_count, batch_size ), verbose=1, epochs=epoch_count, batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch )
else:
        loss_history = model.fit( X, Y, verbose=1, epochs=epoch_count, batch_size=batch_size )
loss_detail = loss_history.history['loss']
loss_text = "{:1.4f}".format( sum(loss_detail)/len(loss_detail) )

model.save( '/home/learning/model/model_'+str(layer_count)+"x"+str(int(node_count/layer_count))+'node_'+optimizer+"_"+loss_text+"loss" )
```

Comment: Can you try without specifying `batch_size` in the `fit` call with the generator?

Comment: So, I changed the fit call to remove the batch_size=batch_size and received the same incorrect model output. Any other suggestions?